# Compiling for Wemos D1 mini with Visual Studio Code

Tags: esp8266, vscode

I'm giving Visual Studio Code (VSC) a try and am getting unexpected results. I have a program (sketch) that compiles fine in the Arduino IDE. I create a workspace in VSC, initialize the project, and after some more mucking about I get a compile there appears to succeed:

```
[Done] Finished verify sketch - RanchMonitor2.ino
```

But the console pane shows four "problems":

[image]

How can the compilation have succeeded if there are problems?

The same sort of thing is happening with one of the samples - HelloServer.ino
In this case the problems are an incomplete type and memcpy_P not defined.

I wouldn't think it should make a difference, but I'm working without a board physically attached to the USB port.

UPDATE:
I think "Problems" are issues identified by Intellisense. They appear even before a compilation is attempted. All I have to do is open the workspace and wait a few seconds, then the "problems" appear. Hence my conjecture they are Intellisense warnings, not compilation errors.
Adding "ESP8266" to the Defines section of c_cpp_properties.json got rid of the error "WiFiManager" is undefined.

Comment: If the compilation fails, it returns error code 1 and doesn't say "finished". I tested this by forcing a failure, removing a semi-colon at the end of a line. See edit to question.

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense reports "Problems" - these are distinct from compile time errors. Just because Intellisense can't resolve a literal or something doesn't mean it won't be resolved in the compiler; thus it's possible to have the IDE report a problem but still be able to have a successful compile. In the case described above, two changes to the c_cpp_properties.json file provided Intellisense with the information it needed. A header file was added to the forcedInclude section to provide pin definitions. A literal "ESP8266" was added to the defines section to indicate the processor type. This define is used in lots of header files so it must be know to Intellisense when reading the headers. Here are the relevant sections of that .json file:

```
        "forcedInclude": [ 
            "C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp8266\\hardware\\esp8266\\2.7.1\\variants\\d1_mini\\pins_arduino.h"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "USBCON",
            "ESP8266"
        ],
```